# Do Web services Redirect the data to the source requested in java

Tags: java, web-services

I had created a web service where it receives the data and store it in database. For confirmation of storage to user i had shown the stored data as response in the same page as (where web service is processing) JSON output.

Now i have a doubt , Do the response can be redirected to the request page.

For your better understanding,

- > A user uploading the data from a html file (upload.html).
- > Now the web service will store the data in database (upload.java) and shows output as JSON in same page (current am using this way)
- > Can i take the response JSON output back to the html (upload.html) and show the JSON output

Is this way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting/sending data of user to server and then again you want to redirect response to the user. **Why?**

When user submits the data you already have it. So just format it and show appropriate message to the user. Showing message after redirection doesn't add any value unless you want to show some message which is coming from server.

**Edit**

[Web service tutorial](http://javapapers.com/web-service/soap-web-service-introduction/)

Check service code in above link; it returns String. Similarly you need to modify your service to return appropriate object.

```
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
}
```

Comment: If the user sending the data i receive in web service and storing it. A confirmation of data or a reference id to be shown in JSON, that too the JSON to be shown on the requested page of user. If i redirect it the Web tool debuugers shows 302 status code.

Comment: don't redirect; send back data as response to the user. You might have to modify your web service to return the response.

Comment: am not understanding how to send back the data as response kindly provide me any suggestions or refer links

Comment: check edit section of my post..hope that helps. You map normal java method to a web service; so just change return type of your method.

Comment: ya it gives me an idea even am doing it in REST. one more doubt i have if user is using the html request from any device will this return statement throws the response to that device?

Comment: yeah..it will throw exception to the client which posted request.

Comment: so its clear that if a client is requesting that html from any device we cant pass the JSON output to the device as response am i right?. Only the client has to call from other way to our web service and get the JSON response

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. how about using jersey having any idea about it. I tried to upload a file to google app engine using REST web service but i got `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)` this exception where i cant go forward after this. Any idea you have on it